# SO Question filtering - Doubt

Tags: discussion, questions

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android?tab=noanswers

Is it meaningful ?

What is the use of `tab=noanswers` under `stackoverflow.com/unanswered/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Unanswered** page, shows you **questions with no upvoted or accepted answers**. You can further filter it down to *questions with no answers* using the *no answers* tab.

Answer (score 1):

Compare that page with:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android?tab=votes

There are different tabs in the page that lists unanswered questions.

I'm pretty sure all of these "question lists" share the same template, meaning they all have a "Unanswered" tab.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the "Unanswered" tab displays questions with no *upvoted* or *accepted* answers (this is explained on the right-hand side of the page).

The "no answers" sub-tab, as specified by that query string parameter, displays questions with no answers *at all*.

This could probably be more intuitive but - to answer your question - yes, it is meaningful.